# Determine the type of error thrown by a function executed by compute

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

In code like the following, `_decodeJson` throws a `FormatException`.

```dart
final invalidJsonString = '{"key":"this is "invalid value" ."}';

try {
  await compute<String, dynamic>(
    _decodeJson,
    invalidJsonString,
  );
} on FormatException catch (_) {
  // error handling
}

static dynamic _decodeJson(String source) {
  return jsonDecode(source);
}
```

However, when I confirm [this part](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/5c407c4be413d094662e5dfefb2044e8d0db53a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/_isolates_io.dart#L39), it seems that the exception thrown by the method executed by `compute` is converted to the `Exception` class.
Is there a way to catch only `FormatException` using `compute` like the above code?

```
Flutter 1.22.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7891006299 (6 weeks ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
Engine • revision ae90085a84
Tools • Dart 2.10.4
```

Comment: Kiri! Hi, did you receive any updates for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can successfully catch FormatException by making it an Exception.